# How to convert join to nested select?

Tags: sql, join, select

I have a simple join and I want to replace it with nested select query.

```
SELECT AspNetRoles.Name
      ,AspNetUserRoles.UserId
      ,AspNetUserRoles.RoleId
FROM AspNetRoles 
INNER JOIN AspNetUserRoles 
    ON AspNetRoles.Id = AspNetUserRoles.RoleId
```

Is this possible? How to do this?

Comment: Any particular reason?

Comment: Depends on the data. But why? A join, or left join, will not fail.

Comment: It is possible, but if you explain your reasoning (do you need to filter the subquery?), or provide an example w/data, you will get better answers.

Comment: I work on the very big database. Tables has too many fields . At the result performance of  join statement is very low

Comment: Well it will be if you're trying to select all millions of rows. Why not filter them based on some indexed column? I'm familiar with these tables; theyre a default provision by Microsoft for managing ASP's built in login/membership system. They don't ahve a problem with their structure per se, or being joined in this way. Any low performance you see will be because of something you're doing (or not doing). You need to present more info, show us the exact query that is slow, not this one that noone would use in a production system for anything other than an irregular one off report

Comment: @Caius Jard the strategy of our project is that use nested select inside join usually.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible?

I'm actually going to go with **no**: as presented, you seem to want the data out of two tables, whose rows are related. This is what JOIN is intended for. If you want to convert the presentation of it to use a coordinated subquery like IN, EXISTS or a sub-select within the select list, you'll simply be making it harder to read (for future developers to maintain), or incapable of returning all the data you want.

Internally the database will most probably plan and execute the queries the same way, so there isn't really much point to stray from the JOIN method. Huge amounts of effort is put (by Microsoft) into determining what data is being requested by a query, and the best strategy for accessing it. This usually involves some amount of rewriting the query you give anyway, so it doesn't make sense to pursue a particular way of writing on a hunch tha tit will be better. Generally you should write your query as simply as possible, let the optimizer in the database figure it out, and if it makes a bad job, then start changing things so it can make a better job. What you've presented here is perhaps the simplest of all queries; a join between two tables in a 1:M relationship, and provided the indexing is sensible and data statistics are up to date, there will be nothing you can do in terms of rewriting it in some horrendous way, to improve on the performance of the strategy the optimizer picks

If you add more info to your question clarifying WHY you feel you need this, we can help more. You've essentially indicated you think there is a performance problem, but I'm guessing you haven't said what the actual query is that you're running (I've a doubt it's literally `SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id`) so if you want help with that, post it up

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this is an inner join but instead of ANSI-92 in ANSI-89 style

You can

```
SELECT        
    AspNetRoles.Name,
    AspNetUserRoles.UserId,
    AspNetUserRoles.RoleId
FROM            
    AspNetRoles, AspNetUserRoles
WHERE
    AspNetUserRoles.Id = (
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            AspNetRoles
        WHERE
            AspNetRoles.id = AspNetUserRoles.id
)
```

But it has no sense, I ashamed to write it, it is slower than using join or an inline where

Comment: What you're doing here is just an [old style join](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), but still a join none the less.

Comment: That is still a join, but instead of ANSI-92 in ANSI-89 style.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know, thank you. I'd like to keep the answer (and edit that) for someone that doesn't know that :)

Comment: Get error : Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: That means that primary and foreign keys are inverted. I edited, try now